# The necessity of edition in some tags’ explanations

Tags: feature-request, tag

As I checked the explanations of several tags in https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags,
I noticed that some of the initial letters of the first words of each explanation begin with Capital-letters, but some of them do not start with Capital-letters. Hence it would be nicer to write all of them by Capital-letters (to be shown more regular)...

For instance:

> ***quran× 427:***
>
> **t**he divine Scripture Muslims believe...
>
> ---
>
> **shiism× 141:**
>
> **T**he Shia (Arabic: شيعة‎, Shīʿah) represent...
>
> ---
>
> ***salat× 426***:
>
> **t**he practice of formal worship in Islam...
>
> ---
>
> **nikah× 272**:
>
> **T**he word nikah (نكاح) translates to...

---

Is that necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click through to the actual tag page, you'll see that all the examples you've given are written in proper English, with capitalization and everything. I believe what you're noting here is unique to the [Tags page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags) itself, where the first couple of words in *most* tag descriptions are considered redundant, and cut off in order to save space.

In particular, if the tag description begins with something like "This tag is…" or "[tagname] is…", it's simply removed from the summary because it's already obvious *what* tag it is.

Comment: Yeah, I meant Taq page, not the actual tag page. / You said " ... are considered redundant, and cut off in order to save space.". Yes, I got that now. Thanks for mentioning that.